# run File_PDF on php 8 (upgrade to Horde_Pdf)

Tags: php, pdf, pear, horde

I use the pear extension File_PDF in an old PHP app I maintain.

It seems like the last version by that module is version 0.3.3 from and it is not maintained anymore and has been superseded by the package `Horde_Pdf` from pear.horde.org.

Can I just change the codebase to the new package? Or do I need to change the function calls?

I started a repository where I convert the old code to the new code at https://github.com/rubo77/File_PDF

The old `PDF.php` was renamed to `Writer.php` and the fonts are now in another folder. and the `class File_PDF` was renamed to `class Horde_Pdf_Writer`.

I replaced the code in my scripts:

and changed

```
    require_once('vendors/pear/File_PDF/PDF.php');
    $this->pdf = &File_PDF::factory();
```

to

```
    require_once('vendors/pear/Horde_Pdf_Writer/Writer.php');
    $this->pdf = new Horde_Pdf_Writer();
```

now I get the error

```
Uncaught Error: Class 'Horde_String' not found in /var/www/app/vendors/pear/Horde_Pdf_Writer/Writer.php
```

Comment: How about you first read documentation, then try to run your new code and find out what kind of errors are thrown? By fixing errors you will know what needs to be changed

Comment: There is no documentation how to upgrade pear "file_pdf" to "horde_pdf_writer"

Comment: Read documentation of `Horde_Pdf`. Your error is because you do not load all needed classes. Try writing some autoloader or just load all needed classes

Comment: But I would suggest to use some more common [PDF libs](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/226/top-5-best-open-source-pdf-generation-libraries-for-php) unless you really need that `Horde_Pdf` lib

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better solution would be to use a more actively maintained PDF generation library like **TCPDF**, which doesn't need much changes either, e.g. from file_PDF to TCPDF just:

- replace `newLine()` with `Ln()`
- replace `getOutput()` with `Output()`
- `SetFont('Arial', ...` doesn't work, so just use `SetFont('', ...`

---

If you really need this old Library you need to also download those packages:

- Horde_Exception
- Horde_Util
- Horde_Translation

To let it run in a local folder, edit some files:

instead of calling File_PDF with

```
require_once('vendors/pear/File_PDF/PDF.php');
$this->pdf = &File_PDF::factory();
```

now call

```
require_once('vendors/pear/Horde/Pdf/Writer.php');
require_once('vendors/pear/Horde/Pdf/Exception.php');
require_once('vendors/pear/Horde/String.php');
$this->pdf = new Horde_Pdf_Writer();
```

in `Writer.php` the function `_getFontFile()` needs these extra lines:

```
$fontname = Horde_String::ucfirst(Horde_String::lower($fontkey));
        require_once('vendors/pear/Horde/Pdf/Font/'.$fontname.'.php');
$fontClass = 'Horde_Pdf_Font_' . $fontname;
```

in `Exception.php` you need to call

```
require_once('vendors/pear/Horde/Exception/Wrapped.php');
```

in `Wrapped.php` you need

```
require_once('vendors/pear/Horde/Exception.php');
```